How to merge Angular 5 table with filtering functionality into recent Angular 18 project
I'm new to Angular 18. I want to integrate filter functionality into existing project. My project is generated with Angular CLI. I don't understand how to merge together older angular 5 code with newer.
The code I'm trying to merge is a material table with filtering functionality, triggered on keyup event.
The code I want to integrate is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hcooj?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html
My code:
main.ts:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import {provideHttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
};

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import {MatToolbar} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatGridListModule} from "@angular/material/grid-list";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, MatToolbar, MatGridListModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'webapp';
}

app.component.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

users/users.component.ts
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {LiveAnnouncer} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatSort, Sort, MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

import { User } from '../models/user.model'; // Define interfaces as needed
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import {UserDetailComponent} from "../user-detail/user-detail.component";
import {MatGridListModule} from "@angular/material/grid-list";
import {MatFormField} from "@angular/material/form-field";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatTableModule, MatSortModule, MatGridListModule, MatFormField
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User>;
  users: User[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name'];

  constructor(private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer, private userService: UserService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.userService.getUsers();
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
      return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) || data.id.toString() === filter;
    };
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  @Input() filter!: User;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  showUserDialog(user: User): void {
    this.dialog.open(UserDetailComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      data: { user: user }
    });
  }

  /** Announce the change in sort state for assistive technology. */
  announceSortChange(sortState: Sort) {
    // This example uses English messages. If your application supports
    // multiple language, you would internationalize these strings.
    // Furthermore, you can customize the message to add additional
    // details about the values being sorted.
    if (sortState.direction) {
      this._liveAnnouncer.announce(`Sorted ${sortState.direction}ending`);
    } else {
      this._liveAnnouncer.announce('Sorting cleared');
    }
  }

  protected readonly HTMLInputElement = HTMLInputElement;
}

users/users.component.html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)">

    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>

The main.ts generated by Angular CLI is quite different from this:
import './polyfills';

import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {TableFilteringExample} from './app/table-filtering-example';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ]
})
export class DemoMaterialModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [TableFilteringExample],
  declarations: [TableFilteringExample],
  bootstrap: [TableFilteringExample],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

UPDATE:
Issue with keyup:
(keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"



You can't use hybrid version for different components in same library, because it makes no sense! For use the last feature of Angular 18, you should upgrade, a little at a time Angular, so you have less breaking code. Consider that angular 5 was released in 2017 and a lot of things have changed in the space of 7 years.
